# What is wrong with this char* [] assignment?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I am having a problem with the following code and I cannot figure it out? If anyone has any ideas, please let me know.

I have two global variables:

`char *newArgv[100], *s[MAXCHAR];`

and one function

```
getword(char *w)
```

in my main function, I make a call to this function by saying

```
getword(s[num]);
```

and in the getword function, I have an assignment that says something like

```
w[index] = 'e';
```

The problem is in that last line of code. The project compiles (obviously) but the program crashes. Anyone have any ideas why? Thanks!

Comment: There is really no way to tell from the question.

Comment: @perh I think it's pretty clear...

Comment: Seems what you want is char new Argv[100], s[MAXCHAR] and not char *?

Comment: If you assume the code above is indeed _all_ there is in the program the issue with uninitialized char * pointers are somewhat obvious, yes, but how is one to know that when the question does not really contain more than description of the code? It could just as well has been omitted. I assumed there was more, though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're dereferencing a NULL pointer.

`s` is an array of `MAXCHAR` NULL pointers. `s[num]` returns the `num`th pointer - which is also NULL. So inside `getword`, `w[index]` is illegal.

You'll need to allocate memory dynamically:

```
for ( int i = 0 ; i < MAXCHAR ; i++ )
    s[i] = malloc(MAX_WORD_LENGTH);
```

Comment: It's a global, so not uninitialized, but initialized to zero.

Comment: @JonathanWakely yes, missed the "global" part.

Comment: Wow, I'm an idiot. Don't know why I didn't think of that. Works now! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

`s[num]` is a `char*` with value `NULL` (because globals are zero-initialized) so when you dereference it, as `w[index]` i.e. `s[num][index]` you dereference a NULL pointer.